# Using GTest/GMock Matcher in EXPECT_EQ

Tags: c++, googletest

I know that matchers are used for EXPECT_CALL, but sometimes I wish I could use matcher to check that 2 objects are the same with EXPECT_EQ (e.g. FloatNear instead of EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ).

Can this be done or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use matchers with `EXPECT/ASSERT_THAT`, see:

```
EXPECT_THAT(42.f, ::testing::FloatNear(41.5f, 0.5f));
```